# Will Paralleling Bridge rectifiers reduce heat in each rectifier?

Tags: bridge-rectifier

So I'm converting an old AC stick welder that only outputs 30 amps into a DC stick welder. I purchased 1000 volt 50 amp Bridge rectifier to do the job but I got two because I thought I might screw one of them up. When they arrived the thought dawned on me to use one per leg of the welder and my thinking on this would be that they was going to be half as much heat in each rectifier because of this. Is that right? is there a reason NOT to split the legs and when I wire it do I need to run ONE AC wire to both terminals on the rectifiers or do I need to split the AC into two pair and wire both rectifiers that way but with only one leg off each rectifier output to the welding clamps. Usually when you see questions about paralleling Bridge rectifiers it has to do with doubling their output but that's not what I want to do at all. I'm definitely going to be below the rating of an individual even if I wired as a single. My thought on this is that I could get away with passive cooling if I'm only putting half the heat out in each spot. Any help you guys have would be great thank you!

Comment: You need to show schematically what you propose. Your words are not good enough to target the detail needed to make an assessment.

Comment: I read your post twice and I have no idea what you are talking about. What does use one per leg mean? like flipflops?

Comment: If I understand the gist of what you’re proposing, then it won’t work. If you put them in parallel, they won’t share equally and there’s no easy way to put them in series. Spliting it into two half bridges gains very little. Nevertheless, at 30A you’ve got around 45W of heat to get rid of. That’s a sizeable heatsink.

Comment: Can use a fan to cool out 45w, is not so big.